# How to call propertychange with combobox using customeditors in propertygrid ext js

Tags: extjs, combobox, propertygrid, propertychangelistener

In ext js propertyGrid,I have customeditor with combobox. I want to enter my own text in combo box rather than selecting from picklist. Then how to retain the entered text in combo and can we apply propertychange to it?

Comment: We can just select the value from combobox dropdown but we cannot use the text that has be manually entered on the combobox in Ext Js. So this will not be possible according to the framework avaliable today.

Answer (score 0):

We can just select the value from the dropdown list of the combobox. But we cannot pass the value by manually entering the value the textfield of combobox. The above implementation will not be possible according to the framework available today